# Sleep() not working with stacked query in mysql-connector-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mysql-connector-python

I am working on creating a security based CTF application in Django. The current exercise I am building is a blind time-based sql injection. As Django does not appear to support stacked queries through `Model.raw()`, I imported the mysql-connector-python which does support stacked queries using the `cursor.execute(query, multi=True)`.

However, when attempting to use `sleep(X)` in the stacked query, the sleep statement won't execute. The following is one example:

view:

```
query = f"select sleep(2); select 1;"

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="****",
    password="****",
    database="****"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, multi=True)

return HttpResponse(f"query: {cursor}")
```

sqli script:

```
url = f"http://127.0.0.1:8080/books/book/?q=1"

start = time.perf_counter()
response = requests.get(f'{url}')
end = time.perf_counter()

print(response.text)
print(f'response time: {end-start}')
```

This will return the following:

```
query: MySQLCursor: select sleep(2); select 1;
response time: 0.005476321006426588
```

However, if dropping multi=True and running a single query, it the sleep will work just fine.

view:

```
query = f"select sleep(2);"

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="****",
    password="****",
    database="****"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)

return HttpResponse(f"query: {cursor}")
```

sqli script:

```
url = f"http://127.0.0.1:8080/books/book/?q=1"

start = time.perf_counter()
response = requests.get(f'{url}')
end = time.perf_counter()

print(response.text)
print(f'response time: {end-start}')
```

This will return the following:

```
query: MySQLCursor: select sleep(2);
response time: 2.010241993004456
```

Note that I have tried using `do sleep(X)` and it also will not execute. This is also a simplistic example as the real meat of the exercise is to read a file (such as /etc/passwd) and use the blind time-based response to pull the data back from a temp table one char at a time.

The query `select sleep(2); select 1;` works just fine in MySQL console and workbench so it should not be an issue with the query itself.

The URL for the execute docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

I have been searching for MySQL documentation as well as questions about stacked queries but can't find anything that makes use of the sleep command.

Thank you all for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked documentation says:

> If `multi` is set to `True`, `execute()` ... returns an iterator that enables processing the result of each statement.

To see `sleep(2)` work, traverse the iterator: `list(cursor.execute(query, multi=True))`.

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood what 'processing the result' means. To me, 'processing the result' means the query has already run and you are processing the result of that query. Not generating the effects of that query. In any case, it seems to do what I need for the sake of this exercise. Though my real SQLi query works in workbench/console but does not work with mysql-connector but that is a problem for a different time. Thank you greatly for pointing out the next step I should have taken.